# Extract array from object in Python

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, object, mat

I have a variable named `mesh` of type `object` extracted from a MATLAB .mat file. (EDIT: Reproducible example below)

```
In [1]: mesh
Out[1]: 
array([[ array([[ (array([[ 89, 108]], dtype=uint8), 
         array([[-131.659809],
          [-131.659809],
          [-131.659809],
          ..., 
          [  52.022239],
          [  52.022239],
          [  52.022239]]), 
         array([[ 189.358345],
          [ 187.271049],
          [ 185.183753],
          ..., 
          [ -29.807736],
          [ -31.895032],
          [ -33.982328]]))]],
         dtype=[('dim', 'O'), ('x', 'O'), ('y', 'O')])]], dtype=object)
```

How can I access the individual arrays `dim`, `x` and `y`?

**Reproducible example:**

I am unable to assign `dtype=uint8` to an array as in the imported object.

Also, the imported object has object size (1,1) while this example has object size (1,1,1,1).

```
import numpy as np

mesh = np.array([[ np.array([[ (np.array([[ 6, 6]], dtype=float), 
     np.array([[-131.659809],
      [-131.659809],
      [-131.659809], 
      [  52.022239],
      [  52.022239],
      [  52.022239]]), 
     np.array([[ 189.358345],
      [ 187.271049],
      [ 185.183753],
      [ -29.807736],
      [ -31.895032],
      [ -33.982328]]))]],
     dtype=[('dim', 'O'), ('x', 'O'), ('y', 'O')])]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, check out [mcve]

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Edited. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: You should be able to access it like `mesh['dim']` and `mesh['x']`... there seems to be a needless wrapping of an `object` type array, i.e., and array of other arrays. so to really dig down, you need to index into that, so for example `mesh['dim'][0]` should return your actual array of dimensions, e.g. `array([[7, 6]])`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, I agree and I can see that there is unnecessary wrapping. But that is the way I am getting the imported data from the .mat file by using `scipy.io.loadmat`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Sorry, I changed the example slightly. 

Actually, I am importing a structure called `dataSRC` having following content:
`dataSRC.mesh` 1x1 struct; `dataSRC.field` 1x1 struct; `dataSRC.pod` 1x1 struct. 
`
The structure `mesh` has following content:
`dataSRC.mesh.dim` [89,108]; `dataSRC.mesh.x` 9612x1 double; `dataSRC.mesh.y` 9612x1 double

Comment: For the latter case, I think you can access the internal data with `tmp = mesh[0, 0, 0, 0]` and `tmp[0]`, `tmp[1]`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the separate arrays above, one could do the following:

```
>>> mesh[0][0][0][0][0] # dim
array([[ 6.,  6.]])
>>> mesh[0][0][0][0][1] # x
array([[-131.659809],
   [-131.659809],
   [-131.659809],
   [  52.022239],
   [  52.022239],
   [  52.022239]])
>>> mesh[0][0][0][0][2] # y
array([[ 189.358345],
   [ 187.271049],
   [ 185.183753],
   [ -29.807736],
   [ -31.895032],
   [ -33.982328]])
```

And to set a value, one could for example do:

```
>>> mesh[0][0][0][0][0][0][0]=1    
>>> mesh
array([[[[ (array([[ 1.,  6.]]), array([[-131.659809],
   [-131.659809],
   [-131.659809],
   [  52.022239],
   [  52.022239],
   [  52.022239]]), array([[ 189.358345],
   [ 187.271049],
   [ 185.183753],
   [ -29.807736],
   [ -31.895032],
   [ -33.982328]]))]]]], dtype=object)
```

#### Disclaimer

This answer is a hack, not a solution. It is not meant to be interpreted as a general answer, but rather is specific to the exact example above. It does not deal with numpy, just with being able to access the specific arrays.